# I want the datepicker to be able to select the date based on browser's timezone - not UTC

Tags: jquery

At 00:01am on 28th (in the UK ) I want to be able to select the current date (28th), but the datepicker wouldn't permit as it took the time as UTC (which was 1 hour earlier: 11pm on 27th. ).

Here is my code:

```
    $("#journeyDate").datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        endDate: '+0d',
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true
    });
    $('#journeyDate').datepicker('setDate', 'today');
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the moment.js library:

```
var todaysDate  = moment().format('dd/mm/yyyy');
```

which returned the browser's date/time.